# Powershell Get-ciminstance error in foreach Loop

Tags: powershell

New to Powershell, trying to use it to update our AD inventory with Serial Numbers from all computers in the environment. I have exported a .csv with all the machine names, and am trying to run through that in a loop from my machine

The script runs fine without the loop-- if I run it and swap the $name variable with a string it works, and if I run it and define the variable and don't loop it work.When in the loop I get this error:

**WS-Management could not connect to the specified destination: (@{Name="PC1"}:5985).**

This is a different error than if I type a hostname that doesn't exist or one that isn't in DNS. It's getting the proper info from the .csv like "PC1". tried using **start-sleep -second 2** to give it some time to connect to each machine but I don't think that's helping.

```
$admachines = import-csv .\Computerinventory.csv
foreach ($hostname in $admachines){
$sn = Get-CimInstance -Class win32_bios -ComputerName $hostname |select-object -expandproperty serialnumber
Set-ADComputer -identity $hostname -replace @{serialNumber = $sn}
}
```

Comment: `$hostname` is not a string - it's an object with a `Name` property. Change `-ComputerName $hostname` to `-ComputerName $hostname.Name` inside the loop and it'll work

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That's exactly what I needed, thank you for your quick response with this concept